# Perf Error While Loading Shared Libraries

Tags: linux, centos, shared-library, perf

I was on `CentOS 7.3` on `x86_64` using `perf` compiled on the system itself from `Kernel 4.13.7` source. It worked without any issue and was able to profile whichever application I wanted to.

For some reason, system crashed and I had to re-configure it. I am back on `CentOS 7.3` with same kernel as it was before i.e. `3.10`. Now, when I downloaded `Kernel 4.13.7` and compiled `perf`, it gives me following error when I try to profile any benchmark.

```
error while loading shared libraries: libiomp5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

As far as I understand, this library belongs to `omp` or `mkl` which I don't need for `perf` and is not present on my system. As per different forums and search, it also seems that this library should come with `Intel MKL`, which is already configured on my system, **but for sure system doesn't have this specific library**.

To debug more, I have another spare system with `RHEL 6.9`. On this system too compiling `perf` as I did for system described above and then profiling same benchmarks gives me same library error.

I am clueless as to why this error is coming up now and wasn't there earlier before re-installing the operation system. I have updated the OS with all the latest packages.

*I don't get this error when I run benchmark standalone (whether `CentOS` or `RHEL`) or with `numactl`, and benchmarks do run-terminate successfully.*

Any suggestion why this may be happening?

Comment: Do you have a ``libiomp5.so``? Can you do a ``ls -ld`` on it and post the output here? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @Scott - `ls -ld` on which binary? Earlier, when I used `perf` for profiling benchmark, it never gave this library error.

Comment: (1) `libiomp5.so`.  If it exists, it will probably be somewhere like `/lib` or `/usr/lib`, and will probably be in a path whose name ends with `…/lib`.  If you can't find it, do `find / -name "libiomp5.so*" -ls`.  (2) So, are you saying that `perf` worked before *on this same computer*?  You should clarify things like that in your question.

Comment: @Scott - I agree, I should have provided more information. Please check rephrased question. If you can suggest any solution, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by re-installing `Intel Parallel Studio XE` which configures different performance library that I need. New install also configured `libiomp5.so` library, which wasn't configured with earlier install.

Then adding path to this library in `/etc/ld.so.conf` and running `sudo ldconfig` solved the issue.

Hopefully, this helps someone.